# Open pull request link in browser after create pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Is any way to open a pull request link automatically in the browser after pushing a branch?
Something like this:

```
git push --set-upstream origin branch-name --open
```

Comment: Since pull requests are not a feature of git, no. You will have to write some [git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) script of your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to automate this via a hook script because there is no `post-push` hook. If you install the [github cli](https://cli.github.com/), you can create an alias that looks something like:

```
git config --global alias.pushpr '!git push --set-upstream origin HEAD && gh pr create -w'
```

Now if you run `git pushpr` it will push your current branch up to a branch of the same name in `origin` and then open the pull request page in your browser.

---

As matt points out in the comment, `gh pr` will actually do this for you *all by itself*. Forget about the alias and just run:

```
gh pr create -w
```

And it will push your branch up to github and open the pull request page.

Comment: `gh pr create` _all by itself_ can do the push and open the web page.

Comment: You know, you're right. I just never use it that way so I forgot. Let me update...

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my git server is bitbucket and it's internal server. I tried to doing your answer but I think it's just for GitHub.

Comment: That seems like the kind of information it would be useful to include in your question. I'm not aware of a similar tool for bitbucket.